# Why does the nth-child color not work in markdown++ viewer?

Tags: css, styles, markdown, background-color

I have the following code:

```
    <style>div.versions_table tr td { padding: 0px 20px }</style>
    <style>div.versions_table tr th { padding: 0px 20px }</style>
    <style>div.versions_table tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: gray}</style>


    <div class="versions_table" >

    | Title | Another|
    |:----------|:------------|
    *aaa*   |   *bbb*
    *bbb*   |   *AAA*
    *bbb*   |   *AAA*
    *bbb*   |   *AAA*
    *bbb*   |   *AAA*
    *lala*   |  <span style="background-color:yellow">*bababa*</span>

    </div>
Which generates the following:
```

[image: example]

So, that makes me understand that:
- Classes work, as the padding is applied.
- Styles of background-color work, because the yellow one is displayed.
- tr:nth-child(even)  is somehow not working

But if I export the output to html:

```
  <style>div.versions_table tr td { padding: 0px 20px }</style>
    <style>div.versions_table tr th { padding: 0px 20px }</style>
    <style>div.versions_table tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: gray}</style>
    <div class="versions_table">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: left;">Ttitle</th>
            <th style="text-align: left;">Another</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>aaa</em>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>bbb</em>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>bbb</em>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>AAA</em>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>bbb</em>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>AAA</em>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>bbb</em>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>AAA</em>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>bbb</em>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>AAA</em>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <em>lala</em>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
              <span style="background-color:yellow">
                <em>bababa</em>
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

So I don´t know if it is some kind of bug in markdown++ or is something that I am missing. Because I can not export to PDF using those colors

Comment: If I put your generated HTML in [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/08zeawh1/), it works as designed, so there's probably some more CSS somewhere else that interferes with the background colors. Can you post a [mcve] that does demonstrate the issue?

Comment: It's likely that the viewer **just doesn't support this CSS selector**. You should dig into their documentation.

Comment: @MrLister that is a minimal reproducible example where I reproduce the problem

Comment: @nck But the markdown you posted here is not the same as the markdown used to produce the screenshot.

Comment: @MrLister Yes it is, maybe a change a word in the list latter, but that is it. I just tested it again and it generates the output from the screenshot.